# rails friendlier routes, change "_" to "-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Imagine the following terminal commands

```
rails g resource HotDogs brand:string
rake db:migrate
```

This will create an endpoint

```
localhost:3000/hot_dogs/
```

I want it to be

```
localhost:3000/hot-dogs/
```

I would like to know how to do this manually without using a gem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Could not find that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a route like
 `get '/hot-dogs => 'controller#action'`
That should work out.